# MVC Views from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building an ASP.Net MVC 2 application for a client and it requires the ability for user to define views.  On this website it shows how to do this - http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views , but I ran into a few comments there and elsewhere that this was a bad idea.  What would be the best way to accomplish allowing users to define the whole page?  Also, why is the database a bad idea?  Thanks.

Wade

Comment: I am not sure why someone would vote for closing, but could you please add a comment to explain where I am out of line?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing for which you might want to consider a Content Management System.

Comment: Amazingly enough that is what I am making.

Comment: @Wade73: Out of curiosity, do you mind if I ask why you're writing your own? There are plenty of great ones out there already.

Comment: Because of the above point.  I have yet to find a CMS that would allow a site admin to build a view.  Now I may not be looking in the right place, so that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Wade73: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. Why do you want your users to be able to create MVC views? Many CMSs will let a site admin add pages and customize a page to their heart's content.

Comment: @Andy, as I said above I want the site admins to be able to build views.  What I should have added was I wanted them to do that through the CMS program and not something like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you can write the application using MVC 3 Beta instead of MVC 2 you can use this technique:

http://buildstarted.com/2010/11/02/razor-without-mvc-part-ii/

You can store your "View" as string in the database then just pull it out and pass it to the parse engine and you are all set.

It works great.

Comment: Ben and Matt did it again.  They have updated this project and put it on codeplex.  http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm no great authority on this but...

I guess the reason it could be a bad idea is you are giving the user root level access to the app, after all arbitrary code can be run from a view.  Also the views will not be checked or tested by programmer, they might not compile or they might have other issues.

You can parse the text supplied by the user that forms the view and try and sanitise it but this is going to be hard.  Although having the MVC view engine as your CMS looks like you are getting the framework to do the heavy lifting for you it's too powerful; expressing in code what the user can't do is harder than expressing in code what they can do.  That's why (maybe) this site uses markdown rather than HTML for markup in the questions and answers.

As for the database being a bad idea I think people might be anti this because of a perceived problem with hitting the db hard.  However I'm not sure this is an insurmountable issue; the view will probably be cached after it has been jit'ed, although I'm not certain, you'll need to test this.  If so you'll have to find a way of causing the jit to run again when a view is edited, or you'll have to recycle the site.  I assume forcing a re-jit exists because when you change an aspx file in a non-precompiled site the framework gets a file change notification from the OS and the updated view is then jit'ed again next time it's accessed.  Even if I'm wrong and the view is pulled out of the db and jit'ed every time it's used you should be able to use caching to stop this happening too much.

In some situations views in a db might be the best approach, for example if the users creating the views are programmers.  I'd consider it very carefully.

As for alternative a CMS toolkit (N2, Orchard etc.) might be a good idea.

Comment: Actually it does cache the view which does cause issues when an edit is made, but I have found a way around that.  What I am hoping to find is a better way.

Comment: Well the obvious way to do it is to alter one of the sites monitored files.  Read web.config and increment a "recycle" counter in it, or change an aspx file.  Then the appdomain will be recycled.  This will be quite expensive.